# How to check a column cell is not empty and copy the file to next column cell, also to a windows folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagridview, filepath

I am try to check if any column1, any of the cell's is not empty. i want to make then empty and copy the file to next column-cell.
What ,my idea is to check if one particular Column1- **all cells** lets say "COLUMN1" one of the cell is not empty.
Then i need the file [ **I have attached the file path to that particular cell**] to get copied to next column2. at the same time i want to copy the file to a folder on my desktop
Lets say the location is **C:/user/elec/copy**, and i want to erase the Column1 -cell data.

How can i do this. Link for what i am trying to do..https://imageshack.com/i/p58FpXoUj

Codes i am trying

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(dataGridView1.Columns["column1"].Cell[i] != string.Empty)
        {
            dataGridView1.row.Cells[0] = dataGridView1.Columns["column2"].Cells[0];// trying to copy the path from column1 cell to column2 cell
            //error above line at row and cells
            string fileName = Convert.ToString(e.Value);//<<--  error here in value
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {

                byte[] objData;

                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
                string fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;
                string s = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();// error here in rowindex..
                objData = File.ReadAllBytes(s);
                File.WriteAllBytes("C:/user/elec/copy", s); //trying to download the file from column1---<< error here

            }

            dataGridView1.row.Cells[0] = string.Empty;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you put the error stack? In this line 'if(dataGridView1.Columns["column1"].Cell[i] != string.Empty)', the var i is from a for each? because it's not there.

Comment: @YanireRomero basically i dont know how to do this.. can you help me with this. i guess its easy to copy a cell path from one cell to another and to save the file in a desktop location. can u please help me the coding. I guess this is not the correct way to do. can you help me

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue!!!!

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string copyPath = @"C:\user\elec\copy";
 if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(copyPath))
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(copyPath);
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != null && 
    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()))
{
    string filePath = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {                   
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string newpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(copyPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, newpath, true);
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = newpath;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SREEJITHMOHA492\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
         {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "update cncinfo set draftpath=@draftpath,releasepath=@releasepath Where part=@part";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@draftpath",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =filePath;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@releasepath",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =newpath;
                cmd.CommandText = "update cncinfo set draftpath='" + string.Empty + "',releasepath=@releasepath Where part=@part";
                //you must have the id value in datagridview to update the specific record.
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@part",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Part Number"].Value);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
         }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        } 
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = string.Empty;
}
}
}
```